# Flexbox element order for nested divs

Tags: css, flexbox

Example is taken from web shop product page, where by default sidebar is displayed before product description. I want to change this and **display sidebar after description**.

I tried to achieve this with CSS flexbox, but I need some help how to display element "description" (3) **between elements** "col middle" (1.2) and "col bottom sidebar" (1.3).

HTML:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="main">
    <div class="col top">1.1</div>
    <div class="col middle">1.2</div>
    <div class="col bottom sidebar">1.3</div>
  </div>
  <div class="tabs">2</div>
  <div class="description">3 (how to move this between elements 1.2 and 1.3 with CSS only?)</div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-flow: column;
}
.main {
  order: 1;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
.top {
  order: 1;
}
.middle {
  order: 2;
}
.bottom {
  order: 3;
}
.tabs {
  order: 2;
}
.description {
  order: 3;
}
```

My fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/bs7hpds7/3/

Comment: I would rather go with JS to move this block than change HTML structure. Can you please tell me something about the ugly way? I need this for mobile view only.

Comment: In the linked duplicate, this answer has a simple script to do just that: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41920277/2827823